# How to get rid of the "home+ return" bar?

Tags: android, eclipse, fullscreen

I have an android app which does run full screen .. done by the mainifest file
Works fine on units with seperate buttons like Samsung s3

Now running the same app on another unit without physical buttoms they will apear in the buttom of the screen see the red cirkel on attached image

I need a hint to remove this bar in code?

http://i44.tinypic.com/35ba1lj.jpg (image)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove this bar for security and usability reasons.

Doing so would make it impossible for the user to exit your app naturally, as both the back and the home button will disappear. Not only is this terrible for usability and system consistency, but it also poses a security risk as malicious apps can take over the system by removing the bar.

Comment: I agree, they should always be visible or at least functional. If those buttons are sensor buttons however, I've seen some applications which hide those, but they ae still functional if you ckick on the place where they should have been.

Comment: @g00dy That'd be when you put it into low profile mode, where the bar is still there and functional, but the buttons are dots instead of the home, back and recents icon. It doesn't hide the bar, just makes it less distinct.

Comment: Yes, that's just what I meant, thanks for clarifying it. However, this might be a workaround for _user2508571_, what do you think?

Comment: hmm... pretty sure it can be done, the unit are a 12" tablet for public use, that why there are no buttons on the front. There are 1 return on the back (hidden). Aklso there are a Demo app on the unit where the bar are removed while it does play some video. So for sure it can be done... but how? :-)

Comment: @user2508571 You can hide it temporarily, but it reappears when the screen is touched. Anything beyond that requires a system modification and rebuild of the entire system image